# Regex and Capital I in some cultures

Tags: c#, regex

What is wrong with capital 'I' in some cultures? I found that in some cultures in can't be found in special conditions - if you are looking for [a-z] with flag RegexOptions.IgnoreCase. Here is sample code:

```
var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
var allLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
var allLettersCount = allLetters.Length;

foreach (var culture in allCultures)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;

    var matched = string.Empty;
    foreach (var m in Regex.Matches(allLetters, "[A-Za-z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        matched += m;

    var count = matched.Length;
    if (count != allLettersCount)
        Console.WriteLine("Culture '{0}' - {1} missing; Matched: {2}", culture.Name, (allLettersCount - count).ToString(), matched);
}
```

Output is (notice missing capital I in every line):

```
Culture 'az' - 1 missing; Matched:          ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'az-Cyrl' - 1 missing; Matched:     ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'az-Cyrl-AZ' - 1 missing; Matched:  ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'az-Latn' - 1 missing; Matched:     ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'az-Latn-AZ' - 1 missing; Matched:  ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'tr' - 1 missing; Matched:          ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
Culture 'tr-TR' - 1 missing; Matched:       ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Interesting is that if flag "IgnoreCase" is not used then it works well, and finds "I".

Comment: Turkey `I` isn't in ASCII, only in Unicode.

Comment: Another reason to use `\w`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I):

> The casing of the dotless and dotted I forms differ from other
>   languages. That implies that a case insensitive matching expected by
>   an English person doesn't match the expectations of a Turkish user.
>   The "Turkish I" is often used as an example of the problems with case
>   insensitivity in computing.

And another explanation can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx#cltsafcode_topic4):

[image]

Comment: In plain words, *when the current system culture is `tr-TR` (Turkish-Turkey), `I` is not the uppercase equivalent of `i`.* See [*Comparison Using the Invariant Culture*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Invariant).

Comment: One more quotation from [Does Your Code Pass The Turkey Test?](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html): *[As discussed by lots and lots of people](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2004/09/04/225720.aspx), the `I` in Turkish behaves differently than in most languages. Per the Unicode standard, our lowercase `i` becomes `İ` (U+0130 “Latin Capital Letter I With Dot Above”) when it moves to uppercase. Similarly, our uppercase `I` becomes `ı` (U+0131 “Latin Small Letter Dotless I”) when it moves to lowercase.*.